# JobScheduler Cannot Accept Parameters. Must Be Empty Constructor

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I am playing around with JobScheduler and I am finding out limitations. I would like to perform a request following a Job, however, I am unable to add parameters to JobScheduler without receiving an error.

> has no zero argument constructor

Here is example code (this works)

```
public class MyJob extends JobService {

 private JobParameters params;
 private MyLargeTask largeTask;

 @Override
 public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
   // get param to use if if needed ...
   this.params = params;
   largeTask = new MyLargeTask();
   largeTask.execute();
   return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
   if (largeTask != null)
     largeTask.cancel(true);

   return false;
 }

  // large task used ...
  private class MyLargeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      jobFinished(params, false);
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // Instead of making a request here, I have to call method outside of the asynctask
      return null;
    }
 }

}
```

If I try to add a constructor, I have no idea how to access it since the only reference to MyJob is during the process of retrieving JobInfo.

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyJob.class);
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName).setRequiredNetworkCapabilities(JobInfo.NetworkType.UNMETERED).setRequiresCharging(true).build();
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

So I am unable to add a constructor such as

```
public MyJob(RequestModel request) {
   ...
}
```

Is there a pattern that can address this issue? My only thought is to create a static method where I execute requests and then call that method in doInBackground. But all of that can be avoided if I can create a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to a job via [`JobInfo.Builder.setExtras(PersistableBundle extras)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setExtras(android.os.PersistableBundle)).

You can't pass normal Java objects, because your app's process may be killed by the time that the job is run.